# Summer school Holland visa requests

Tags: visas, netherlands

I am Ethiopian and in my last year of study and employed in Rwanda. I will have a break in July and want to spend it in Holland at summer school for two weeks. I've already been accepted.

1. Does my local health insurance work? If so must it be 30euro?
2. The Belgian consulate handles the Dutch cases and am told it almost auto rejects it. Is that true? Must I travel to Nairobi to apply directly at the dutch embassy?

Given the above, should I cancel my plan?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It is not quite clear to me what you are asking, what do you mean by your local health insurance and what do you refer to by 30euro? Concerning your last question about cancelling, that is an opinion and we only do facts so best to edit your question to cancel that part. Also it would be best to ask your questions 1. and 2. as separate questions.

Comment: You would not go to Nairobi to avoid using the one in Addis Ababa, that would open more questions than it would allegedly solve.  Please use the suggestion from @mts (to whom thanks) and break up your question into manageable parts.

Comment: As @Gayot noted, the reference to Nairobi is indeed strange -- but since the OP appears to be a resident of Rwanda, he must [apply at the Belgian embassy in Kigali](https://www.government.nl/topics/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/documents/publications/2014/02/20/embassies-responsible-for-short-stay-visa-for-the-netherlands), rather than Addis Ababa.

Comment: Not related to your question, but if you do come to the country: some Dutch, especially those who do not live in Holland, can be (slightly) insulted if you call the country Holland. It's a minor thing, but I thought I'd mention it! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does my local health insurance work? If so must it be 30euro?

No, your local health insurance does not meet the guidance for the Schengen visa program. The minimum required coverage is 30,000 Euros.

You will have to purchase specific insurance for your trip.

> The Belgian consulate handles the Dutch cases and am told it almost
>   auto rejects it. Is that true? Must I travel to Nairobi to apply
>   directly at the dutch embassy?

A lot of questions may be raised if you are applying from another domicile. As long as your documentation is correct and you are **applying for the right type of visa** you should have no issues.

Keep in mind the counselor is looking for proof that you will return after your visit to your home country - and specifically looking for reasons why (like say, you have a job, family, property, etc.)